# Django testing function with request.user

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I'm trying to write a test for a custom function in my Django model and having some issues.  The function works correctly tested manually so this is a test code issue.  I have read all the related questions on this but they have not solved my problem. I am using pytest.

Code examples below:

models.py - I want to test this function

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.in_progress:
        MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user, flag=True).update(flag=False)
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

tests.py

```
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = UserFactory.create()

    def test_that_works(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/mypage/')
        request.user = self.user
        response = my_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_that_doesnt_work(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/')
        request.user = self.user
        myitem = MyModelFactory.create()
        myitem.flag = True
        myitem.save()
        assert myitem.flag is True
```

When I run these tests, the first test works, but the second says 
    `NameError: global name 'request' is not defined`

The full traceback makes it clear that it is getting to `myitem.save()` in the test and the error is something to do with passing the `request.user` into the `save()` function.

Comment: The problem isn't your test - it has identified a problem with your `save()` method. You don't have access to the `request` inside the `save()` method.

Comment: Thanks sorted now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting `request` in model `save` method but it's not declared, your are not passing it even from `myitem.save()`, do following changes:

**in tests.py**

```
myitem.save(request=request)
```

**in models.py**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request')
    # other code
```

Keep in mind that `save` method will always requires `request`, probably not a good idea. If you still want to stick with it then I would suggest pass `user` explicitly to model save method, as you are not doing anything else with the `request`:

**in tests.py**

```
myitem.save(user=request.user)
```

**in models.py**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('user')
    # other code
```

Comment: Thank you I understand where I am going wrong now however the above doesn't work, I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment` or `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment` for the second option

Comment: Opps Sorry! forgot quotes around key for `kwargs.get()`. Updated answer.

Comment: The save method needs to check which user is logged in before saving so I definitely need to get the current logged in user somehow.

Comment: Excellent thank you so much for your help! I have used `kwargs.get('user')` and it works now, I have updated answer with this.

Comment: Great! `.get` will return and keeps the user in kwargs but will not return None if key not found, `.pop` will remove from kwargs but raise `KeyError` if not found, it depends on you what you expect it to be.